# Can it be improved further?

Tags: java-8, functional-programming

I am new to java8. Just wanted to know, this is correct way to write java 8 and suggest if given code can be improved further with respect to java8 functional programming?

```java
public class OperationByJava8 {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        Operation op = (num1, num2) -> num1 + num2;
        return op.operate(a, b);
    }

    public int subtract(int a, int b) {
        Operation op = (num1, num2) -> num1 - num2;
        return op.operate(a, b);
    }

    public int multiply(int a, int b) {
        Operation op = (num1, num2) -> num1 * num2;
        return op.operate(a, b);
    }

    public int devide(int a, int b) {
        Operation op = (num1, num2) -> {
            if (num2 == 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("denominator cannot be zero");
            }
            return num1 / num2;
        };
        return op.operate(a, b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OperationByJava9 op = new OperationByJava9();
        System.out.println("    Addition(12, 12)    :" + op.add(12, 12));
        System.out.println("    Subtract(12, 12)    :" + op.subtract(12, 12));
        System.out.println("    Multiply(12, 12)    :" + op.multiply(12, 12));
        System.out.println("    Devide  (12, 12)    :" + op.devide(12, 12));
    }

}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Operation {
    int operate(int a, int b);
}
```

Comment: There's no point in creating these `Operation`s if you all you do is immediately call them. You might just as well do without the lambdas.

Comment: Yeah, I felt the same that why am I doing this but wanted to know lambda exp. As @Aomine said, I understood that and change my code accordingly. "Learning by doing and mistakes :-)"

Comment: I guess, `OperationByJava9` is supposed to be `OperationByJava8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is completely fine and would be good to proceed with.

if you want to further reduce the code, you could create a single function as follows for addition, subtraction and multiplication.

```
public int apply(int a, int b, IntBinaryOperator func) {            
      return func.applyAsInt(a, b);
}
```

but then you'll need to create a separate function for the division functionality in order to throw the `IllegalArgumentException` exception in the case of the second argument being `0`.

Note that i've used the `IntBinaryOperator` functional interface to avoid having to create the `Operation` interface but if the latter is more meaningful then you can keep that.

Alternatively, you can define the functions inline and then invoke them:

```
IntBinaryOperator add = (num1, num2) -> num1 + num2;
IntBinaryOperator subtract = (num1, num2) -> num1 + num2;
IntBinaryOperator multiply = (num1, num2) -> num1 + num2;
IntBinaryOperator division = (num1, num2) ->  {
        if (num2 == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("denominator cannot be zero");
        return num1 / num2;
};


System.out.println("    Addition(12, 12)    :" + add.applyAsInt(12, 12));
System.out.println("    Subtract(12, 12)    :" + subtract.applyAsInt(12, 12));
System.out.println("    Multiply(12, 12)    :" + multiply.applyAsInt(12, 12));
System.out.println("    Devide  (12, 12)    :" + division.applyAsInt(12, 12));
```

Comment: As a side note, the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("denominator cannot be zero")` is not better than the `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` you’ll get when just using `(num1, num2) -> num1 / num2` with a zero argument, so that pre-test is just visual noise.